# What is wrong with my code? Keep getting "unexpected end of file" after checking every bracket and semi-colon

Tags: php, database, forms, validation

I'm trying to setup the validation file for a form that requires the user to re-enter login info in order to confirm they want to delete their account. I got it to work when I tried it with hardcode but now it won't even throw an error on the front-end, just shows the "page not working" screen on Chrome. I've scrutinized the code for any missed `{`, `}`, or `;` and didn't see any. Even tried phpcodechecker.com and nothing. Either I'm blind or something else is going on. Here it is:

```
<?
if((empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) or strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') or empty($_POST)){
  exit("Unauthorized Access");
}
require 'user/inc/config.php';
require 'user/inc/functions.php';

if (!$db) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST['Action']=='delete_acct_form'){
    $Return = array('result'=>array(), 'error'=>'');

    $email = safe_input($db, $_POST['delEmail']);
    $password = safe_input($db, $_POST['delPassword']);

    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $Return['error'] = "Email or Password invalid";
    }elseif($password===''){
        $Return['error'] = "Email or Password invalid.";
    }
    if($Return['error']!=''){
        output($Return);
    }
        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE email='$email' AND password='".md5($password)."' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $Return=$_SESSION['UserData']["user_id"];
    }else {
        $Return['error'] = 'Invalid username or password.';
    }
}
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id=$Return";
if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    echo "Your account has been deleted";
}else{
    echo "There was a problem with deleting your account."mysqli_error($db);
}
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a dot to concatenate the string you echo at the end:

```
echo "There was a problem with deleting your account." . mysqli_error($db);
```

Comment: I agree with answer, for future you can use PHP code checker tools for analyze your errors. http://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: I actually removed that for this post, it was already in the code but I'll add it again. @ONLINE TELEKOM - I did use the code checker and it came up with no errors. Update: Re-added the . and still error

Comment: @ONLINETELEKOM - With the . back in place as it was before this question, it shows none. Like I said, I took it out for this post by mistake so I added it again and still same problem.

Comment: Are you find some solution or ?